# PHP documentation for yield (rvalue) as coroutine

Tags: php, concurrency, coroutine

You can create a generator in PHP that yields values:

```
function genOneTwoThree() {
  foreach ([1,2,3] as $i => $number)
    yield $i => $number;
}
```

Then you can consume them like:

```
foreach (genOneTwoThree() as $i) {
  echo $i;
}
```

This "lvalue" usage is documented here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield

But yield can also be used as an rvalue like this:

```
function printer() {
  while (true) {
    $string = yield;
    echo $string;
  }
}
$printer = printer();
$printer->send('Hello world!');
$printer->send('Bye world!');
```

This "consumer" example is given in the "Generator" documentation at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/generator.send.php

Is there another place that actually documents this type of usage? Some other specific question I have are:

- Can rvalue yield functions return something, and when does that happen?
- What happens when rvalue yield functions affect global state
- Can you use rvalue and lvalue yield to filter a generator?

Comment: You can combine both using `$string = (yield $i => $number);`

Comment: In order: [Generators RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generators), [Generator Return Expressions RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generator-return-expressions), and [Generator Delegation RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generator-delegation).